# Firebase new Date()?

Tags: javascript, datetime, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and I was wondering how I can store a JavaScript date and use Firebase to compare them on the client side later?

I want to do something like:

```
var someDate = new Date();
myRootRef.set(someDate);

myRootRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
     var currDate = new Date();
if (currDate >=  snapshot.val()){
     //do something
}
```

However, I get back a value of `null` from the snapshot?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also use timestamp.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
myRootRef.set(timestamp);

myRootRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var currDate = new Date();
    var snapshotTimestamp = snapshot.val();

    //you can operate on timestamps only...
    console.log("Snapshot timestamp: " + snapshotTimestamp);

    if(currDate.getTime() >= snapshotTimestamp) {
        //do something
    }

    //...or easily create date object with it  
    console.log("Snapshot full date: " + new Date(snapshotTimestamp));

    if (currDate >=  new Date(snapshotTimestamp)){
        //do something
    }

});
```

Comment: Additionally, unless both dates are from the same client, you'll probably want to consult `.info/serverTimeOffset` and add that to the timestamp:  `new Date().getTime() + offset`; otherwise you're going to get some weirdness for users who don't keep their clock synced within a second of atomic time

Comment: thanks for the replies and code samples! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -3):

You need to set a Firebase with string or object with value, and than read the same value in the event.

```
    var someDate = new Date();
    myRootRef.set({Date: someDate.toString()});

    myRootRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var msg = snapshot.val();
     var currDate = new Date();
    if (currDate >=  msg.Date){
     //do something
    }
    });
```

Comment: Comparing dates as strings won't achieve a correct date comparison, so you'll probably want to use the timestamp approach recommend by @ghost.